# How to determine which label is considered the 'positive' class in H2O binary classifier?

Tags: h2o

Training a binary classifier using h2o.ai and would like to know which label is being considered to be the 'positive' class. This makes a difference since if have labels say, 'give cookie' and 'don't give cookie', and are trying to optimize to maximize *recall*, depending on which label is the 'positive' class we will be giving out more ('give cookie' is positive class) or less ('don't give cookie' as positive class) cookies.

Another post on SO ([How do I specify the positive class in an H2O random forest or other binary classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44089162/8236733)) seems to imply that level values are assigned by alpha order by default ('a' being the lowest level and 'z' being the highest) and just trying to confirm here as it's own explicit question.

Also, is there a way to see which class is currently the 'positive' class for a model (ie. based on the ordering of the confusion matrix labels when using the `some_h20_model.confusion_matrix(...)` output command)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are verifying is correct, H2O-3 orders levels in lexicographical order.

You can use this confusion matrix as an example of how a confusion matrix will be ordered (i.e. if you have categoricals and you sort them in alphabetical order they will map over to the 0,1,2... as shown)

[image]

And here is an example of a binary outcome with No and Yes, where No maps to 0 and Yes maps to 1.

[image]

Comment: So just to be totally clear, when assigning levels in lexicographical order, the highest value level (9 in the first example and 1 in the second example) will be the one considered the "positive" class, right?